# Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on null problem

Tags: php, laravel

I have a section on the site where used items parsing from Steam API. Every item has an attribute `market_hash_name`, `classid`, and i have virtual items on the site which have constant value `market_hash_name` and `classid`, and these values do not change.

Items that are in the Steam service are stored in the database, the virtual items on the site are not stored in the database, but generated via json on the fly.

The site has the function of transferring items from the Steam service and virtual items to each other. Items that are in Steam (and they are registered in the database) are transmitted without problems, but virtual items are not transmitted (because that don't have in database), and response an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on null line: 851`

My code:

```
    foreach ($itemsInfo as $item) {
        if (isset($item['classid'])) {
            $itemDB = Item::find($item['id']);

            $itemDB->update([
                'steamid' => $user->steamid64,
                'status' => 0
            ]);
        }
    }
```

At 851 line i have `$itemDB->update`.

The problem arises because I try to transfer virtual items, they are not in the database and therefore I get this error, because in the `items` table there is no my value `classid` for virtual items. How can i correctly set the condition, for example `if item has classid == test, than use another code;`?

Comment: try checking the $itemDB maybe that have null value

Comment: Yes, it gets a null value, but I need to make a selection, that if a items with a certain classid, so that need use another code

Comment: `if (is_null($itemDB) { continue; }` for skip null value

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in earlier comments, you should check the returned value of the find() method :

```
    foreach ($itemsInfo as $item) {
        if (isset($item['classid'])) {
            if($itemDB = Item::find($item['id'])) {

                $itemDB->update([
                    'steamid' => $user->steamid64,
                    'status' => 0
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```